# ValidationMessageFor return all the time error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the jquery validation script, in addition, I create a validation on the server side. for some reason, I got all the time error message from the server even when the text fields values are correctly defined.

this is my view file:

```
 @model StudentsManagment.Models.student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" id="studentForm">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">            
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_name,new {@class = "form-control", name = "First_name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_name, new { @class = "form-control", name = "Last_name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, null,new { @placeholder = "Date: MM-DD-yyyy",@class = "form-control", name = "Date_of_birth" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_of_birth)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Student_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Student_id, new { @class = "form-control", name = "Student_id" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_id)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City,new { @class = "form-control", id = "citySearch" , name = "City" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,8,1, new { @class = "form-control",name = "Description" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#studentForm').bootstrapValidator({
            container: '#messages',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                First_name: {
                    validators: {                        
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 20,
                            min:2,
                            message: 'The full name must be between 2-20 characters'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/i,
                            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical english characters and spaces only'
                        }


                    }
                },
                Last_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 20,
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'The full name must be between 2-20 characters'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/i,
                            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical english characters and spaces only'
                        }
                    }
                },
                Date_of_birth: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The birth date is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The date is not valid',
                            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'                           
                        }
                    }
                },
                Student_id: {
                    validators:{
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Student id is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                            message: 'The student id should conatin only digits'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 9,
                            min: 9,
                            message: 'The student id  must be 9 digits'
                        }
                    }                    
                },
                Description: {
                    validators: {                                               
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 1000,                         
                            message: 'The description field should be less than 1000 characters '
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#citySearch").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCountry",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.CityName,
                                value: item.CityName
                            };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "No Results was found",
                results: function (resultCount) {
                    return resultCount + (resultCount > 1 ? ' results' : ' result ') + ' found';
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

and this is my model:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StudentsManagment.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public  class student
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="First name field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")]
        [Range(2, 20)]
        public string First_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")]
        [Range(2, 20)]
        public string Last_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth date field is required")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime Date_of_birth { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student id field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\b]+$")]
        [StringLength(9)]
        public string Student_id { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the controller function is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(student studentToCreate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }          
        _db.students.Add(studentToCreate);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

i found that the problem was in my _Layout.cshtml file for some reason when i removed those lines it didnt gave me the error:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

but now i am getting the following error after i click on create:
[image]

Comment: It's a bit strange that you're not even validating the anti-forgery token and you're getting validation errors. Are the errors triggering on the client-side or after you do a postback? Also, shouldn't you pass the `studentToCreate` model to the `View` method when model state is invalid?

Comment: its occur in the client side even before i click on create. intimidate after i insert the text the error is occur.

Comment: Have you control the model data transmitted by your form to the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove simply **RangeAttribute** on those fields which must be used on numeric fields ;-)

If you want to control Length use the right one

[MSDN - StringLengthAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i just remove [Range] and instead use [StringLength] this was resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove regular expression from firstname and LastName

Comment: this is will not help me because this fields should get only English letters